# Mysql joining Query

Tags: mysql, database

I am working on a project and I got stuck into a problem as I have three different tables as shown in the query and snapshots.
 I tried to execute the below query and pasting the result of the query

Query

```
 select 
m.id,b.paybandname,m.payheadid,h.payheadname,m.basedon,find_in_set(h.id,m.basedon) as 
basedonone,m.amount,m.type from tblpay_paybandsystem b
 left join tblpay_payheadmapping m on b.id = m.paybandid
 left join tblpay_payheads h on m.payheadid = h.id
```

Result

[image]

What I want is based on column I want payheadname for example in third row we have 6 in based on column but I want payheadname which is "Basic" for id=6 
Now  I am pasting the snap shots of the tables used in the above query

tblpay_paybandsystem

[image]

tblpay_payheads

[image]

tblpay_payheadmapping

[image]

Comment: i want payheadname in place of basedon which contain payheadid

Comment: Pictures? That's not how we roll. Post up proper DDLS and/or an sqlfiddle TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT

Answer (score 0):

This should do it (not tested):

```
select 
m.id,b.paybandname,m.payheadid,h.payheadname,h2.payheadname,find_in_set(h.id,m.basedon) as 
basedonone,m.amount,m.type from tblpay_paybandsystem b
 left join tblpay_payheadmapping m on b.id = m.paybandid
 left join tblpay_payheads h on m.payheadid = h.id 
 left join tblpay_payheads h2 on m.basedon = h2.id
```

Comment: typo: last join should be on h2.id - also notice the h2.payheadname in the "select" clause where there used to be m.basedon

Comment: i am not getting u please mention the proper query so that i can understand it in better way..thank u

Comment: I fixed my answer so that the proposed extra join is now "left join tblpay_payheads h2 on m.basedon = h2.id" (I mistyped it earlier as h.id instead of h2.id)

Comment: in tblpay_payheadmapping we have basedon field in which we have 6+7 as payheadid so i want 6+7's payheadname from tbl_payhead table...which i am not getting from above query

Comment: the case of "6+7" will be next to impossible to do with clean sql. Depending on how many combinations you're expecting here (just 6+7, or also many others like 1+2+3, 9+123....) it may be reasonable to create combined entries in your tblpay_payheadmapping table. Not exactly elegant but I don't see a quick solution on how to split and look up each individual entry (6 and 7 in your example). Sorry